# Get Lightning domain name from Visualforce page and vice-versa

Tags: visualforce, lightning, iframe

I am using visualforce page inside a lightning component as an iframe. For communication, i use `parent.postmessage(message, origin);`. Problem is, that at the moment i have hardcoded URL's, but when i deploy to production the domain names will be different.

In lightning experience, i need visualforce URL to confirm, that the message is coming from an expected origin.

How can i get lightning experience domain from visualforce and how can i get visualforce domain name from lightning experience?

Comment: Did you try giving a relative URL like ./apex/testvf? instead of hard coding the entire URL in iframe

Comment: I can use relative path in lightning component, but in visualforce i need to set lightning experience origin, where to send the data

Comment: this works in our org in community <iframe src="../apex/ISD_UploadDocuments"../>

Comment: In visualforce page where you use postmessage, do you use  "*" as origin? I read, that it is very bad practice to do it thisway.

Comment: This question, and answers has now been superseded by https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/390075/get-lwc-domain-in-vf-and-vf-domain-in-lwc

Ideally, this should now be marked as a duplicate

Answer (score 2):

I use a class below for this purpose:

```
public without sharing class UTIL_Domain {

    public static String getVisualforceDomain(){
        return getMyDomain() + '--c.' + getInstance() + '.visual.force.com';
    }

    public static String getLightningDomain(){
        return getMyDomain() + '.lightning.force.com';
    }

    public static String getMyDomain(){
        return URL.getOrgDomainUrl().getHost().split('\\.')[0].toLowerCase();
    }

    private static String instance = '';
    public static String getInstance(){
        if(String.isBlank(instance)){
            instance = [SELECT InstanceName FROM Organization LIMIT 1].InstanceName.toLowerCase();
        }
        return instance;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the domain by piecing it together yourself from the Visualforce domain or the Lightning Experience domain, but it is error-prone and brittle because your salesforce instance number could change and Salesforce has been changing URLs.

Instead, I recommend simply storing the expected origin URL as custom metadata. Then you can customize it per instance and if your instance number changes then you can update the URL without pushing any code.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution for this now is described here:

- [Get LWC Domain in VF and VF Domain in LWC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/390075/get-lwc-domain-in-vf-and-vf-domain-in-lwc)

Essentially:

> The DomainCreator class (added in the Spring 22 release) does this.
>
> https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_domain_classes.htm&type=5&release=236

For example:

```
String myVfHostname = DomainCreator.getVisualforceHostname(null);

String myLightningHostname = DomainCreator.getLightningHostname();
```

Note, if passing a namespace into `getVisualforceHostname`, you may need to do some manual conversion prior to sending it.  That is, if your internal namespace has an underscore in it (e.g. `an_app`), the URL version will have the underscores replaced with dashes (e.g. `an-app`).  This should be done prior to passing it into the method.

E.g.  Assuming that `yourNamespace` contains the Apex namespace for your app:

```
DomainCreator.getVisualforceHostname( yourNamespace.replace( '_', '-' ) );
```