# Whitelisting Visualfoce URLs in my Application

Tags: isv, whitelisting

I'm using a third party tool (AWS Quicksight) to embed a dashboard into an SFDC ISV application. This tool requires all domains where the dashboard is embedded to be whitelisted (not whitelisted in SFDC but directly in Quicksight). So each time I have a new customer who uses my application I've been asking them to copy their URL and send it to me so I can whitelist it. An example of the domain I'm whitelist is "https://MYCOMPANY--four-cast.naXX.visual.force.com" (where "MYCOMPANY" and "XX" are unique to the org).

Is there a way for me to whitelist all SFDC domains/sub-domains?

Comment: This is more of an AWS question than a Salesforce question. Have you tried asking on the AWS forums?

Comment: Does AWS allow wildcards, or partial domain matching, so you just list either *.force.com or force.com?

Comment: Can this post help you? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/217335/get-lightning-domain-name-from-visualforce-page-and-vice-versa